# Butter Knife ocClick Adapter RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, butterknife

From one of the display text I will give the clicklistener function. Coding above is coding in the adpater list. I use the Butter knife repository. can my friends help me fatherly to make click listener function?

```
public class AllproductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.txt_id)
    TextView txt_id;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_id_product_category)
    TextView txt_id_product_category;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_id_currency)
    TextView txt_id_currency;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_name_product)
    TextView txt_name_product;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_price_capital)
    TextView txt_price_capital;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_price_sale)
    TextView txt_price_sale;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_description)
    TextView txt_description;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_sku)
    TextView txt_sku;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_stock)
    TextView txt_stock;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_condition)
    TextView txt_condition;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_deliverable)
    TextView txt_deliverable;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_downloadable)
    TextView txt_downloadable;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_target_gender)
    TextView txt_target_gender;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_target_age)
    TextView txt_target_age;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_visibility)
    TextView txt_visibility;
    @BindView(R.id.image)
    ImageView image;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_image)
    TextView txt_image;


    public AllproductHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add `onClickListener` to specific view after binding

Comment: can you see the code for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `@OnClick` annotation to your ViewHolder class. Something like this:

```
public class AllproductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   ...

   public AllproductHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
     ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

   }

    @OnClick(R.id.image) // Change to your view id.
    void onImageClicked() {
      int position = getAdapterPosition();
      // Do something for related item.
    }

}
```

Comment: If the image is clicked, it will appear intently through the String that I brought to the next activity. '        @OnClick(R.id.image)
        void onImageClicked() {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            // Do something for related item.
            Intent detail = new Intent(getContext(), DetailProduct.class);
        }'

Comment: `         @OnClick(R.id.image)
        void onImageClicked() {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            // Do something for related item.
            Intent detail = new Intent(getContext(), DetailProduct.class);
        }`

Comment: If the image is clicked, it will appear intently through the String that I brought to the next activity. ' @OnClick(R.id.image) void onImageClicked() { int position = getAdapterPosition(); // Do something for related item. Intent detail = new Intent(getContext(), DetailProduct.class); }'   @ישו אוהב אותך

Comment: What do you trying to achieve? Opening an activity when clicking the View?

Comment: I think you can simply do that by using the following code: `Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DetailProduct.class) ;`

Comment: yeah right, when I click on the image, what appears is the detail of the textview and image @ישו אוהב אותך

Comment: You need to create the intent with: `Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DetailProduct.class) ;`. Then set the intent payload with `intent.putExtra()`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q85le0 no work , this force close apps @ישו אוהב אותך

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q85lv7 line 128
https://prnt.sc/q85m05 line 43
https://prnt.sc/q85m5g line 29

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches, just change `txt_id` in to your desired view:

```
// you can use this approach
    public AllproductHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        txt_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
            }
        });
    }

// or this
    @OnClick(R.id.txt_id) 
    void onImageClicked() {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
    }
}
```

Since you are using `ButterKnife` I would suggest second approach

Comment: If the image is clicked, it will appear intently through the String that I brought to the next activity. ' @OnClick(R.id.image) void onImageClicked() { int position = getAdapterPosition(); // Do something for related item. Intent detail = new Intent(getContext(), DetailProduct.class); }' @Antonis Radz

Comment: adapter position should be used to take desired image from your data list

Comment: I would suggest to exam few examples and documentation how Android Adapter and RecyclerView patterh works and it is implemented